# Looping through informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, flat-file

I have a flatfile with 2 fields:

```
   Old_Value | New_value
       57    |    59
       55    |    57
       43    |    55
       41    |    43
```

Now I am supposed to update records having 57 with 59, 55 with 57, 43 with 55, likewise.

As you can see in above example I will be updating all records having values 41,43,55 and 57 with 59 ultimately.

How to achieve this in informatica?

I am using only flat files and we don't have any database system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Informatica doesn't have a simple way to update a flat file.

One option would be to create a mapping where the file to be "updated" is the source, use a flat file lookup on the 2 column file, compare the old and new values, update where necessary and write out the full file again once you are done.